# Как забиндить Width у ColumnDefinition?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

Есть `ColumnDefinition` и `Grid`, который имеет проперти `Grid.Column = "0"`, то есть является дочерним элементом `ColumnDefinition`. Мне нужно, чтобы `Width` этой колонки менялся в зависимости от `ActualWidth` моего Дочернего грида.
Данный код не работает:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=GridMainInfo, Path=ActualWidth}" />
```

Comment: Вы делаете что-то не то. Если хотите, чтобы дочерний элемент имел такую ширину, как он хочет, используйте `Auto`.

Comment: @VladD можно сразу в ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, вам нужно просто

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
```